# File Upload to a cross domain WCF service using jquery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, wcf

Here is what I am trying to do (unsuccessfully, I might add) and would appreciate any direction you can give me

From my HTML5  site, I want to upload a file to a cross domain WCF service that is hosted in IIS 7.5.

In addition to uploading the files, I need to send additional parameters to the upload function on the server

Is this possible to do?

Here is what my operationContract looks like:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke( Method = "POST",
UriTemplate = "/uploadmodeldata/?id={Id}&customerdatatype={customerdatatype}&data={data}")]
void UploadModelData(string Id, string customerdataType, byte[] data);
```

Here is what my jquery ajax request

```
function FileVisits() {

    var uid = checkCookie1();
    userid = uid.toString().replace(/"/g, '');
    var fileData = JSON.stringify({
   Id:userid ,customerdatatype:scanupload,
        data: $('#fileBinary').val()
    });
    alert(fileData);
        "use strict";
        var wcfServiceUrl = "http://xxxxx:1337/Service1.svc/XMLService/";
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: wcfServiceUrl + "uploadmodeldata/",               
            data: fileData,
            type: "POST",
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json",
            timeout: 10000,
            dataType: "json",
            headers:    {
                        'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible) Greasemonkey',
                        'Accept': 'application/atom+xml,application/xml,text/xml',
                    },
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


            },
            complete: function () {
                $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            },

            success: function (data) {
                var result = data;


            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });

}
```

if file size is less then 100 kb this error occurred

> Method not allowed

but if file is greater then 100 kb this error occurred

> 413 Request entity to large

How can I upload a file from jquery ajax to cross domain wcf.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the `Method not allowed` cause you are trying to call a service on another domain. This violates the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). This is a security limitation. Most older browsers will deny such requests.

You will need to setup  [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) if you want to access a different domain the webservice in javascript.

> Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows a web
>   page to make XMLHttpRequests to another domain. Such "cross-domain"
>   requests would otherwise be forbidden by web browsers, per the same
>   origin security policy. CORS defines a way in which the browser and
>   the server can interact to determine whether or not to allow the
>   cross-origin request

If you have access to the webservice code, you can enable CORS requests at the server.
[Enable cors](http://enable-cors.org/) is a good resource. Here is some [explaination on cors](http://encosia.com/using-cors-to-access-asp-net-services-across-domains/)

On IIS 7, you need to set a few custom headers in your web.config.

```
<system.webserver>
 <httpprotocol>
  <customheaders>
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
  </customheaders>
 </httpprotocol>
</system.webserver>
```

[Here are the steps for IIS6](http://enable-cors.org/server_iis6.html)

As for the 413 error, that is related to the max file size you allow on your binding

```
<bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
    </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Solve this issue. Actually i have used binding name in wcf config. After removing binding name every thing  working properly.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a lot of work but here is my code(in case someone needs it):

```
$("#UploadFileBtn").click(function () {     
    fileName = document.getElementById("filePicker").files[0].name;
    fileSize = document.getElementById("filePicker").files[0].size;
    fileType = document.getElementById("filePicker").files[0].type;     
    var file = document.getElementById("filePicker").files[0];
    if (file) {
    // create reader
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var content = e.target.result;
        content = content.substring(content.indexOf('64') + 3);
        bhUploadRequest = "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" " +
                                             "xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" " + 
                                             "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" " +
                                             "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">" +
                             "<SOAP-ENV:Header>"+
                                "<m:FileName xmlns:m=\"http://tempuri.org/\">" + fileName + "</m:FileName>" +
                                "<m:Length xmlns:m=\"http://tempuri.org/\">" + fileSize + "</m:Length>" +
                             "</SOAP-ENV:Header>" +
                             "<SOAP-ENV:Body>" +
                                "<m:RemoteFileInfo xmlns:m=\"http://tempuri.org/\">" +
                                    "<m:FileByteStream>" + content + "</m:FileByteStream>" +
                                "</m:RemoteFileInfo>" +
                             "</SOAP-ENV:Body>" +
                         "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            url: wsFtransferUrl,
            data: bhUploadRequest,
            timeout: 10000,
            contentType: "text/xml",
            crossDomain: true,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/IFileTransferService/UploadFile");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("TICKET", Ticket);
            },              
            success: function (data) {
            alert('succes');
                $(data).find("UploadFileResponse").each(function () {
                    alert($(this).find("UploadFileResult").text());
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert('error:' + error);
            }
        });

    };
}
    return;

    });
```

and here is my WCF transfer service:

```
public void UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request)
        {   
            string filePath = string.Empty;
            string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            int chunkSize = 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
            long progress = 0;

            filePath = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, request.FileName);

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
                File.Delete(filePath);

            using (FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
            {
          do
                {
                    // read bytes from input stream
                    int bytesRead = request.FileByteStream.Read(buffer, 0, chunkSize);
                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                        break;
                    progress += bytesRead;                    
                    // write bytes to output stream
                    writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                while (true);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the "POST". To solve the problem do the following

Create a Global.asax and add following to enable Ajax cross-domain POST.

```
 public void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST,OPTIONS");

            if ((HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS"))
            {

                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
```